# scrape html source vba

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping

I need to **scrape** some info from web, using vba. This is an extract of my code. It's ok, but the site has 2 classes with the same name. So my code writes only the last value. I want that:

Sheets("01").Range("DW" & number) = source.getAttribute("data-id")

writes only the first value of class "sample" found on site.

How can I do?
Thanks

```
 With http
    .Open "GET", site, False                
    .send
    html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
End With
For Each source In html.getElementsByClassName("sample")

Sheets("01").Range("DW" & number) = source.getAttribute("data-id")  

       
Next source
Next number
```

Comment: It seems you're not showing all of your (relevant) code. You have a `Next number`-statement but no matching `For` or `For Each` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To refer to the first element of a class collection, you can use the Item property, for which the index is 0-based.  So you can replace your `For Each/Next` with the following line...

```
Sheets("01").Range("DW" & Number) = html.getElementsByClassName("sample").Item(0).getAttribute("data-id")
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

You can be more efficient by using `querySelector`, which only returns the first match rather than an entire collection (or nodeList)

```
Sheets("01").Range("DW" & Number) = html.querySelector(".sample").getAttribute("data-id")
```